# How to conclude each $E_i$ is a compact regular domain by Proposition 5.47?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

[image]
[image]

In Proposition 5.47, $M$ is a smooth manifold, but in Theorem 6.15, $M$ is a smooth manifold with or without boundary, how to conclude each $E_i$ is a compact regular domain by Proposition 5.47?

Comment: I believe Proposition 5.47 holds for manifolds with or without boundary. Maybe check the proof of 5.47 (and the theorem it aludes to) to see whether it works for manifolds with boundary as well.

Comment: Can you prove it?

Answer (score 2):

This excerpt is from my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (2nd ed.). There's a correction to this proof on [my website](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/). Does that answer your question?

Comment: But how to show $E_i$ is a smooth manifold with or without boundary?

Comment: It might not be. That's the point of the correction -- the argument works for any compact _subset_ of a smooth manifold with or without boundary, and $E_i$ is such a subset.